# How To Put If Statement Inside Transaction Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

When the user clicks a button it's going to check if the Document in Firestore is exists or not, if it is, then just update (increase) some value, and if it isn't create a new document with the new value.

I could just do the normal `documentRef.get()`, and `documentRef.set()`, but when I tested it with 2 user press the button at the same time. Its just put the new value of one of them. and so I used transaction.

In this transaction, first I get the documentsnapshot, and I get the value.
and then I put if statement to check if the document is exist, the first statement which is document is exist is working fine, but when I deleted the document, the else statement didn't do anything.

Is it even possible to use if statement inside Firebase Firestore transaction?

```
Map<String, Object> newDocumentSet = new HashMap<>();
        newDocumentSet.put("sold", 1);
        newDocumentSet.put("price", myProductPrice);

mDb.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {

                DocumentSnapshot myDocumentSnapshot = transaction.get(myDocumentRef);
                long newAddSold = myDocumentSnapshot.getLong("sold") + 1;
                long newAddPrice = myDocumentSnapshot.getLong("price") + myProductPrice;

                if(myDocumentSnapshot.exists()){

                    transaction.update(myDocumentRef, "sold", newAddSold);
                    transaction.update(myDocumentRef, "price", newAddPrice);

                }else {

                    transaction.set(myDocumentRef, newDocumentSet);

                }


                return null;
            }
        });
```

I don't know what's happening, it didn't show any error, please tell me if I made some mistake or there is another way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or there is another way of doing this..

Yes there is, even a simpler one which in fact is more efficient than a transaction because it does **not** require a round trip between the client and Firebase servers. Assuming that the `mDb` points to the correct document, to increment the `sold` property by `1`, please use the following line of code:

```
mDb.update("sold", FieldValue.increment(1));
```

Comment: but what if there is a lot of users, isnt that what transaction for?

even if it can, is it work to create the document when the document doesnt exist?

Comment: The transactions are meant to be used when you need to read the data from the server first and then change it. For a simple increment operation there is no need for a transaction. That's the reason why,  Firebase implemented this option. It doesn't matter how many users you have, this solution will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to return a `Map<String, dynamic>` value from the `runTransaction` function and inside the run transaction make sure you return a map value like

```
if (a) {
  return "value":true
} else {
  return "value":false
}
```

Then in the return statement of your function assign `mapDynamic["value"];`. Then you will now which part of your code was executed. mapDynamic is just a variable name.